# .net security exception

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.net security exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225991/net-security-exception)

I am using OpenFileDialog class to browse a file in window application using c#. It is giving the security exception as below.

> Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission,
>   mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

My code is

```
    OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog(); 
    fdlg.Title = "C# Corner Open File Dialog"; 
    fdlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\"; 
    fdlg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*"; 
    fdlg.FilterIndex = 2; 
    fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true; 
    if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
    { 
        txtpath.Text = fdlg.FileName; 
    }
```

I am not getting the problem. please help.

Comment: Please don't duplicate questions!